# insert & fetching RSA encrypted data in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, cryptography, rsa

We are `encrypting data ( string )` with `RSA algorithm`. 
Then we are trying to insert this `encrypted data` to `SQLite Android database` using `varchar type`. But whenever the `encrypted data` contains single quote ('), the data is not inserted as we are using `varchar`.

Please suggest which `data` type we have to use to hold the encrypted data in `database`.

If `insertion` of `encrypted data` is success, then we are not able to `decrypt` the `data` that we are fetching from the `SQLite database`.

Please suggest some solution.

```
    char* encryptValue(char* value)
{
    char msg[KEY_LENGTH / 8];
    strncpy(msg, value, sizeof(msg) - 1);
        msg[(KEY_LENGTH / 8) - 1] = '\0';
        LOGD("Message is: %s", msg);


            LOGD("gen rsa8");

            LOGD("Message is %s",msg);
            fgets(msg, KEY_LENGTH - 1, stdin);
            LOGD("gen rsa8a");
            msg[strlen(msg)] = '\0';

            LOGD("Message is %s",msg);
            LOGD("gen rsa8b");

            LOGD("gen rsa8b1");

            LOGD("value of r size is: %d", RSA_size(r));
            encrypt = malloc(RSA_size(r));


            err = malloc(130);

            if ((encrypt_len = RSA_public_encrypt(strlen(msg) + 1, (unsigned char*) value,
                        (unsigned char*) encrypt, r, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)) == -1) {
                    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
                    LOGD("gen rsa9a");
                    ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
                    LOGD("gen rsa10");
                    //LOGD(stderr, "Error encrypting message: %s\n", err);

                    //goto free_stuff;
                    RSA_free(r);
            }


            // Write the encrypted message to a file
            //int c = 0;
            LOGD("gen rsa10b");
            FILE *encryptFile = fopen("/sdcard/encrypt.txt", "w");
            LOGD("gen rsa10c");
            fwrite(encrypt, sizeof(*encrypt), RSA_size(r), encryptFile);
            LOGD("gen rsa10d");
            fclose(encryptFile);

            //LOGD("gen rsa11");
            //printf("Generating RSA (%d bits) r...", KEY_LENGTH);
            LOGD("encrypt sizeof: %d", strlen(encrypt));
            LOGD("Encrypt is: %s", encrypt);
            //LOGD("encrypt sizeof: %d", strlen(encrypt));
            LOGD("Encrypt_len value is %d", encrypt_len);
            //printf("Size Of Encrypt: %d", strlen(encrypt));

            return encrypt;
}

char *decryptValue(char* value)
{
    // Read it back
        //  printf("Reading back encrypted message and attempting decryption...\n");

        LOGD("*********Value of r size is: %d", RSA_size(r));
        encrypt = malloc(RSA_size(r));

        LOGD("*********Value of value field is: %s",value);

        //strncpy(encrypt, value, sizeof(encrypt) - 1);
                //encrypt[strlen(encrypt)] = '\0';

        LOGD("*********Value of Encrypt is: %s",encrypt);

        LOGD("*********gen rsa12a");

        LOGD("*********gen rsa12b");

        LOGD("*********gen rsa12c");

        LOGD("*********gen rsa12d");


        decrypt = malloc(encrypt_len);
        LOGD("*********Encrypt_len value is %d", encrypt_len);
        //LOGD("Value of msg length is: "+ strlen(msg)+1);
        LOGD("*********Length of Encrypt is %d", strlen(encrypt));
        LOGD("*********Value of Decrypt is: %s", decrypt);
        LOGD("*********gen rsa12e");
        if (RSA_private_decrypt(encrypt_len, (unsigned char*) value,
                (unsigned char*) decrypt, r, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) == -1) {
            ERR_load_crypto_strings();
            ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);

            LOGD("*********gen rsa13");

            RSA_free(r);
        }


        LOGD("*********Decrypted message: %s\n", decrypt);
        LOGD("*********Decrypted String length is %d", strlen(decrypt));
        return decrypt;

}
```

Comment: A single quote is understood by an SQLite Database in different terms. You need to handle that using parameterized  queries. Please share your insert and select query. You can check [here](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/137025/parameterized-query-for-sqlite-db-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-titanium) for a select query and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255538/sqlite-insert-text-with-single-quote-got-from-a-sql-request) for an insert query

Comment: That link for the select query is for Titanium, not native Android, so it will not translate exactly.  But that is the idea and you should be able to find resources for how to do it.

Comment: @nasch thanks matey, for rectifying!

Comment: @Skynet My INSERT Query contains encrypted data which may contain Single Quote ('). Below I mentioned my INSERT Query which used               SQL Insert Query is: INSERT INTO acl(source_id,command_id,fingerprint,app_id,rule_type) VALUES ('<?-?z'??0\?+???/',4,'encryptFingerPrint','encryptAppId','encryptRuleType'):

Comment: @Skynet And I using the RSA algorithm for encrypting data. So, please suggest me some solutions for this.

Comment: Did you look at the link he posted for inserting?  That will tell you how to do it.  @Skynet any time!